# Склоняется ли слово «шпигат»?

Tags: склонение

Склоняется или не склоняется слово *шпигат* (отверстие в корпусе корабля)?

Comment: Можно узнать, почему Вы усомнились? Все слова мужского рода, оканчивающиеся на согласный, склоняются. Все, понимаете. Без единого исключения.

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, склоняется! Смотрите [тут](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%88%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82&all=x): ШПИГАТ, -а; м.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы. Ответы–ссылки  не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Вообще-то я не только ссылку привел, но и ответил на сам вопрос и процитировал из ссылки. Этого мало?

Comment: Да, спасибо! Как мне кажется, было бы здорово добавить обоснование в том или ином виде в тело ответа.

Answer (score 2):

"Повалил пар — кто-то направил струю из шланга на раскаленные обломки, застрявшие в переборке. Убитые в **шпигатах**; раненых уносят прочь."

Форестер, "Лейтенант Хорнблауэр"